# Content type header value resulting in UnsupportedMediaType 415 OpenFeign

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, feign, openfeign

We recently upgraded to `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign: 2.2.2`  from version 2.0.0 and we encountered the following exception when calling the REST API that uses `consumes` and also having `@RequestHeader` Content-Type:

```
    feign.FeignException$UnsupportedMediaType: [415] during [POST] to [http://localhost:8080/test]
    [TestFeign#test(TestRequest,String)]: [{"timestamp":"2021-01-03T13:13:58.192+0000",
    "status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type",
    "message":"Invalid mime type \"application/json, application/json\": 
    Invalid token character ',' in token \"json, application/json\"","path":"/test"}]
```

Our Feign Interface is defined as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes= {"application/json"},
produces={"application/json"})
void test(@RequestBody TestRequest request,@RequestHeader("Content-Type") String contentType);
```

We investigated and saw that in this case both values are being concatenated as follows:

```
Content-Type: "application/json, application/json"
```

When using `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:2.0.0` this issue does not occur.

Comment: Could you please verify against the current Hoxton version (2.2.6) and see if there's still an issue?

Comment: We tried to use Hoxton.SR9 (which uses spring-cloud-starter-openfeign 2.2.6.RELEASE) and we still get this issue